# Apple Accelerate vDSP fft vs DFT and scaling factors

Tags: ios, macos, signal-processing, accelerate-framework

I am an experienced programmer but I don't have a lot of experience implementing DSP routines.

I've been banging my head against this for weeks if not months. My question is two fold, concerning Apple's Accelerate framework:

1)

In the vDSP.h header there are comments to the effect of: please use vDSP_DFT_XXX instead of the (i guess) older versions vDSP_fft_XXX. However there are *zero* examples of this outside of Apple's https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/samplecode/vDSPExamples/Listings/DemonstrateDFT_c.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004300-DemonstrateDFT_c-DontLinkElementID_6. Maybe it's just that the DFT functions are newer? If so, fine and dandy.

2)

Scaling factors. I can read the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/UsingFourierTransforms/UsingFourierTransforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005147-CH202-16195), it says in the case of an FFT on a real input, like audio that I am working with, the resulting value of each of the Fourier coefficients is 2x the actual, mathematical value.

And yet, in every example, including Apple's own, the scaling factor used for the resulting vsmul() function looks like it is 1/2*N instead of 1/2 as I would expect.

Further, there is no documentation about the scaling factors for the vDSP_DFT_XXX routines, but I assume that they just wrap the older ones?

Any insight into either of these questions would be greatly appreciated! Hopefully I'm just missing something basic about the way that FFT's are implemented in this framework (or in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 3 different FFT scaling options that produce "mathematical" results, and there is no single standard scaling.  Energy preserving (see Parseval's theorem) FFT libraries need to be scaled by on the order of 1/N for input magnitude results, since a longer signal of the same magnitude will have proportionally more energy.  vDSP uses an energy preserving forward FFT.

Comment: Nice. Thank you. I did not know about Parseval's theorem. Tons more to read up on now!

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting this topic, but I didn't get the answer. If vDSP uses energy-preserving forward FFT, why is there a need to scale by 1/2? Doesn't the product of the 2 (fft, ifft) scaling factors need to be 1? If this is the case, then are we correcting/complementing a bad/incomplete scaling done by the vDSP by scaling to 1/2 for forward and 1/N for inverse? This means that the forward is, by default, scaled with 2N, doesn't it?

Comment: For strictly real signals, half the energy of any spectrum are in thier complex conjugate bins of the FFT result.  You can add the two equal magnitude bins, or more commonly, just scale one of them by 2X and ignore the other half of the FFT result array (for many reasons).

Answer (score 0):

On part 1), two [answers in the Apple developer forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23321) say "The DFT interfaces are newer and a little bit easier to use correctly, and support some lengths that the older FFT interfaces cannot." and "plus there are new DFT routines that support working directly with interleaved data"